# How can I get HTML element onClick from WebView in Windows 8 Metro app?

Tags: c#, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a simple Win8 Metro app which has three pages, one of which is WebView.
Let's say that I have some html code that I'm showing in WebView that contains something like

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">Go to site</a>
```

How can I detect click on that HTML element, recognize element and get data (let's say "http://www.mysite.com") from the element?
Is that even possible in Metro apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these members:

[LoadCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.loadcompleted.aspx)  - to wait until your page is loaded,

[InvokeScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) - to subscribe to an event inside HTML,

[ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx) - to be notified from JS.

Answer (score 1):

If you control the content for mysite.com, it can be done.  You can add Javascript on your site to fire an event via `window.external.notify` that can raise an event in your C# using [WebView.ScriptNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx).  See How to receive information from the WebView in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx) for an example.

Unfortunately, there is no way to intercept navigation (unlike other web views).